# Connecting Odoo to Power BI

Tags: database, powerbi, odoo, connector

A client needs me to create a dashboard for his business and has provided me with admin account access to a URL that looks like this: http://159.2xx.251.4x:8xx9/web#action=87&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Now I am unable to locate where the 'database' tab is so I can retrieve all the required connection detail when I try to establish a connection between the client's database and the Power BI Dashboard (Client Analysis) file. On the other hand, I can easily locate where the 'Database' tab is if the account was created on  [www.odoo.com/my/databases](http://www.odoo.com/my/databases). Is it because of the nature of the platform which reflects on the format of the URL having an IP address?

Please how can I possibly address this issue so I can establish a connection between the Odoo platform and Power BI Dashboard (Client Analysis)?

I will really appreciate your response

I tried navigating to locate the database using the admin login details but couldn't find it